# I want to block all ip address except office ip

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, ufw

I am running simple rails application on `ubuntu` and I am using `nginx` as my web server. I would like to block all ip address except our office ip address(static ip).

Now I can block ip using `nginx`

```
location / {
   allow office_ip_address;
   deny  all;
}
```

or I can block ip using `ufw` uncomplicated firewall.

```
sudo ufw allow from office_ip_address
```

(will this block all other ip? or do I need some command to block all other ips?)

I would like to know which approach is better? I think it's better to block ip on firewall level so request don't come to our server at all. I am new to setting up servers so please advice me which way is better?

Comment: Yes, you should do it from the firewall. No reason to allow connections farther in than necessary.